# Connection refused when trying to open, write and close a socket a few times (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, limit, max

I have a program that listens on a port waiting for a small amount of data to tell it what to do. I run 5 instances of that program, one on each port from 5000 to 5004 inclusively.

I have a second program written in Python that creates a socket "s", writes the data to port 5000, then closes. It then increments the port number and creates a new socket connected to 5001. It does this until it reaches 5004.

The first three socket connections work just fine. The programs on ports 5000 to 5002 receive the data just fine and off they go! However, the fourth socket connection results in a "Connection Refused" error message. Meanwhile, the fourth listening program still reports that it is waiting on port 5003 -- I know that it's listening properly because I am able to connect to it using Telnet.

I've tried changing the port numbers, and each time it's the fourth connection that fails.

Is there some limit in the system I should check on? I only have one socket open at any time on the sending side, and the fact that I can get 3 of the 5 through eliminates a lot of the basic troubleshooting steps I can think of.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

I'm on CentOS Linux with Python version 2.6. Here's some example code:

```
try:
        portno = 5000
        for index, data in enumerate(data_list):
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(('myhostname', portno))
                s.sendall(data)
                s.close()
                portno = portno + 1
except socket.error, (value,message):
        print 'Error: Send could not be performed.\nPort: ' + str(portno) + '\nMessage: ' + message
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: There's really not enough information to usefully troubleshoot this.  Try to narrow it down with small scripts that just do the basic socket stuff, and if you still can't figure it out, include those simple scripts.

Comment: What version of python are you running? And on which platform (os)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your program, not much we can help with unless you can show some code. You can debug a bit with the netstat program though, which'll show the connection states of all processes on your machine.

Comment: Fire up wireshark and watch to see if the packets are beign generated and rejected, or aren't making it onto the wire at all.

Comment: Can you try five other ports like 6000 to 6004 and see if you still get the problem on last port. If you do, its most likely a bug in your program.

Comment: Your code sample works for me in python 2.5.1 and 2.6 on Mac OS X, using the server part of the answer I gave below (everything before `time.sleep`) as something to connect to, `"localhost"` instead of  `"myhostname"`, and using `data_list = map(str,range(10))` as data. What does your server code look like?

Comment: Could you please comment on the answers given below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the anti-portscan measure of your firewall kicking in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that much about sockets, so this may be really bad style... use at own risk. This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading, time
from socket import *
portrange = range(10000,10005)

class Sock(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )

    def start(self):
        self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(("localhost", self.port))
        self.s.listen(1)
        print "listening on port %i"%self.port
        threading.Thread.start(self)
    def run(self):
        # wait for client to connect
        connection, address = self.s.accept()
        data = True
        while data:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            if data:
                connection.send('echo %s'%(data))
        connection.close()

socketHandles = [Sock(port) for port in portrange]

for sock in socketHandles:
    sock.start()

# time.sleep(0.5)

for port in portrange:
    print 'sending "ping" to port %i'%port
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.connect(("localhost", port))
    s.send('ping')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print 'reply was: %s'%data
    s.close()
```

should output:

```
listening on port 10000
listening on port 10001
listening on port 10002
listening on port 10003
listening on port 10004
sending "ping" to port 10000
reply was: echo ping
sending "ping" to port 10001
reply was: echo ping
sending "ping" to port 10002
reply was: echo ping
sending "ping" to port 10003
reply was: echo ping
sending "ping" to port 10004
reply was: echo ping
```

perhaps this will help you see if it's your firewall causing troubles. I suppose you could try splitting this into client and server as well.

Comment: In the socket examples in the Python library docs, they don't send without receiving. Sockets can be fussy things so perhaps all the acks are being buffered until socket.recv() is called and after his third port, the buffer is full and gets stuck in some kind of wait state.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the 2nd Python program from within Idle?  If so - try it outside of Idle and see if the results are any different.